# Header views height for grouped UITableView on iOS7

Tags: header, uitableview, ios7

I'm building my settings screen and using a grouped table view.
When trying to set the headers I see spacing above my header view.
I double checked and I do pass the correct view height in `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`.

Here is a screenshot of this behavior: 
[image]

You can see my view with the title (VIBRATE, SILENT MODE) in it and it's darker bg color and the brighter space above it.

Comment: So what's your question? And this is still NDA, you should ask in the developer forums.

Comment: How to get rid of the space above my header view.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

After much searching, I have finally found a fix for this. The tableview's delegate needs to implement heightForFooterInSection and return a very small number. Returning 0 defaults to the same spacing that was causing the extra spaces.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the behaviour is quite incoherent. All values return the correct height but 0, which returns a default height. This is not documented and the behaviour appears to be incoherent. I opened a radar for this.

Comment: @viggio24 Thanks for that! Please keep us inform of the advancement.

Comment: @naudec Thanks. CGFLOAT_MIN is probably a better return value. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. Returning 0 does not stop default behaviour of UITableView which renders the footer.

Comment: For anyone trying in Swift,
`CGFLOAT_MIN` is unavailable, the compiler will nicely tell you to use `CGFloat.min`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    CGRect frame = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:headerView];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think that this will affect the table's top header only and I'm talking about section's header.

Comment: This is actually an legit solution- The system doesn't add the extra space to the first section header if a `tableHeaderView` exists. Personally I prefer this trick over messing with footer height.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty much the same as Casey's response, however, it is a bit cleaner as it doesn't require implementing a delegate method. When you are setting up your table view, simply set the property `sectionFooterHeight` to 0. It accomplishes the same thing with less code (and no `DBL_MIN` oddness).

`tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0.0;`

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it is just a simple hack. But an easy way to do it is to write this function:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      return 48.0f; // header height
}
```

to customize its height.

Pretty sure there are other ways to do it, that I don't know of.

Comment: thanks for answering. Already have this method implemented. I return the correct header view height, but still get the extra ~20 px spacing above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Apple made a conscious design decision to make grouped table views have extra space on top. Try adjusting the contentInset of the `UITableView`. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18935526/1374512)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.2 version:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.min
}
```