# iOS tableview's size differs from tableViewWrapperView's size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView which always has a blank space under navigation bar, after I debugged in view hierarchy I found the tableView's size differs from tableViewWrapperView's size. Any idea?[image]

[image]
[image]

The following is the code of the tableViewController that I'm having problems with:

```
#import "BBTCampusInfoTableViewController.h"
#import "BBTCampusInfoManager.h"
#import "BBTCampusInfoTableViewCell.h"
#import <UIImageView+WebCache.h>

@interface BBTCampusInfoTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation BBTCampusInfoTableViewController

extern NSString * campusInfoNotificationName;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveCampusInfoNotification) name:campusInfoNotificationName object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    //self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    //Retrive all campus infos
    [[BBTCampusInfoManager sharedInfoManager] retriveData:@""];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[BBTCampusInfoManager sharedInfoManager].infoArray count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 140.0f;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.5;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    return view;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"infoCell";
    BBTCampusInfoTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[BBTCampusInfoTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    NSArray *infoArray = [BBTCampusInfoManager sharedInfoManager].infoArray;

    [cell setCellContentDictionary:infoArray[indexPath.row]];

    [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveCampusInfoNotification
{
    NSLog(@"Did receive campus info notification");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty space before cells in UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906919/remove-empty-space-before-cells-in-uitableview)

Comment: I've read that one but his methods don't work for me.

Comment: @Caeser since you have apparently tried everything (And nothing works for you somehow), Add the links to the methods you have read and which do not work for you. Otherwise people will keep repeating the usual methods and waste everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are keep saying it doesnt work, try this, its a kinda ugly workaround, but it works. (see the image)

- simply just add some UI component before table view -

[image]

This will happen if table view (or scrollview) is the only / first sub-view on the container view.

As a solution you can un-tick  Adjust Scroll View Insets
See below image

[image: Adjust Scroll View Insets]

Comment: see my updated answer - but this should have worked - may be your autolayouts settings are off

Comment: In your case you added a tableView in a viewController? I simply dragged a tableViewController.

Comment: Actually never seen UITableViewController behave like this (normally UITabelView in UIViewController has this issue). Any way can  you see this gap in InterfaceBuilder too, or is it just when you run the app on a device. May be try deleting this UItableViewController in IB and drag and drop new UItableViewController. :)

Comment: This only happened when I run my program on the simulator, it won't appear in the interface builder. I've tried drop a new one several times but makes no sense :(

Answer (score 0):

if using interface builder, try:

Select the view controller, 
Open Attributes inspector, 
The "Adjust scroll view insets" is on by default.

or programmatically try:

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

in the viewdidload

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding this code to `viewDidload`:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Or try this code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.5
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    return UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
}
```

Comment: I tried it but the blank space became even wider :(

Comment: @try to edit to 0.5 Or you can upload class table you are using.

Comment: It's the same with the situation that I didn't add the code. Please see my updated question.