# 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets' was deprecated in iOS 11.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, deprecated

I just started compiling up to iOS 11 and noticed that Apple now declared the property

```
var automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets: Bool { get set }
```

as being deprecated:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621372-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewin

[image]

Is there another property to fix this warning in iOS 11?

Will the default value stay true or how will this be handled in future?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The default for this property is now true. If you need to set this, you will need to set it in the scrollview that would host the viewController and set its property contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior. Below is an example:

```
scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .automatic
```

Comment: Albeit I used ".never" because I had set it to false, this one seems to be the proper replacement! Thank you.

Comment: How can I handle it?? self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

Comment: @RajasekharPasupuleti `scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`

Comment: if you're using a collectionView then it's **collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never**. If it's a tableView then: **tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never**

Comment: for scrolling view will     collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
 this work

Answer (score 125):

This code may help:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Comment: what is `scrollView` here?

Comment: @AlexeyStrakh scrollView is whatever `UIScrollView` that is having the insets adjusted. For example on a `UICollectionViewController` it would be `self.collectionView`, on a `UITableViewController` it would be `self.tableView`.

Comment: Tested: This works for iOS 11 and iOS 10.  Great thanks.

Comment: This might work, but it doesn't make the warning go away.

Comment: @GordonTucker I had a BaseViewController from UIViewController & there I was making `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets ` to false.
Now the problem occurs as I will have to do it separately on each viewcontrollers. 
Is there any better way to handle this at one place?

Answer (score 7):

You can also set this in Interface Builder. Select your tableView or collectionView then select from the drop-down in the Size Inspector select .never for 'Content Insets Adjustment Behavior'

[image: Size Inspector]

Answer (score 2):

For those who are wanting to adjust this from an objective-c perspective, here is the code:

```
self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever
```