# UITableView padding in iOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have a plain `UITableView` displayed in a `UIView` class.

When scrolling to top or bottom it displays white padding.

There are no header\footer views to this table.

This problem occurs only in iOS7.

Here is a screen shot of how it looks

[image]

[You can see the white rectangle above digit '1'. I have the same at the bottom]

So far I have tried:
1. tweaking the contentInsets' - it worked, *BUT* it disabled the ability to scroll the table.
2. UnCheck the "Top Bars", "Bottom Bars" and "Opaque Bars" attribute in IB - Didn't help.

and other stuff that where offered in other posts.

Any idea?

Comment: Check also the adjust scroll insets from IB. Especially if your table view is the first view in your view controller's view.

Comment: I've tried setting scrollInsets - it did nothing!

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst?rq=1)