# why extra space is at top of UITableView - simple

Tags: ios

I'm picking up some iOS programming and am trying to put a UITableView into a storyboard. Unfortunately, I am trying to put the content at the top of the view but it is putting in some space. I have tried to adjust the values in the inspector for View -> Mode but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

I have made the background green and put a border color to show the issue. I'm not a sophisticasted iOS dev, so I'd assume that this is the simplest solution and not something complex. How do I make the contents of the table view sit flush with the top? I've seen this [Why is there extra padding at the top of my UITableView with style UITableViewStyleGrouped in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst) but not sure if it's related.

thx for any help

[image]

---

### Edit #1

Updated with changes and screen shot of properties for this table view

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes, related to - [Why is there extra padding at the top of my UITableView with style UITableViewStyleGrouped in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes, that other question is very much related. `UITableViewStyleGrouped` divides each section into a "group" by inserting that extra padding…similar to what it did pre-iOS7, but clear instead of colored by default, and just at the top instead of all the way around.  If you don't want the padding by default, use `UITableViewStylePlain`.

Otherwise, if you need to keep the style the same, do what this other posted from that link recommended and change the content inset:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-36, 0, 0, 0);
```

Or do what this poster suggested and set the `tableHeaderView`'s `height` to `.-1`, i.e. nearly `0`:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 0.01f)];
```

Comment: Hmm... I am pretty sure it is set to UITableViewStylePlain (have included screenshots).

Comment: Thanks for your contentInset. self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);  in ios 8 with navigation bar.

Comment: Better replace the magical number `0.01f` with `CGFLOAT_MIN `, as is shown in the related post.

Comment: Scenarios when this solutions won't work 1. If you have different color on the header and different on the footer. 2. initWithFrame with 0.01f crushes on iOS 10 with exception that header can't be with negative value -1 means must be from >1 etc.

Answer (score 58):

Go to the attributes inspector of the View Controller by selecting the xib or the controller in Storyboard. Uncheck the **Adjust Scroll View Insets** in **Layout**. It will solve the problem[image]

Comment: To set it programmatically,  `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 8):

Everybody keeps talking about this `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` option.
However this did not work for me at all. What did work for me, was setting the "Content Insets" property to `Never`.

[image: screenshot demonstrating where to find the setting]

Such an annoying problem.

Answer (score 6):

In Swift, you just need to set the below property to false.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Answer (score 5):

It is very easy and worked for me perfectly. 
Select a controller in Story Board in which you placed UITableView.

YouStoryboard.storyboard > YouViewController > Attributes inspector > Uncheck - Adjust scroll view insets.

Make sure you select UIViewController not UITableView.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift :**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None

       OR

self.moduleListTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-64, 0, 0, 0);

       OR

 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake( 20, 20 , 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

in swift 3.0, i hope will help you

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it can be fixed easily through Storyboard:

Select Table View > Size Inspector > Content Insets: Never

Answer (score 0):

Cause of this issue:-

1. a UITableView doesn't like to have a header with a height of 0.0. If what's you're trying to do is to have a header with a height of 0, you can jump to the solution.
2. even if later you assign a non 0.0 height to your header, a UITableView doesn't like to be assigned a header with a height of 0.0 at first.

In ViewDidLoad:-

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

No Need For Something Like This :-

```
self.myTableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-56, 0, 0, 0)
```

In `heightForHeaderInSection` delegate:-

```
if section == 0
    {
        return 1
    }
    else
    {
        return 40; // your other headers height value
    }
```

In `viewForHeaderInSection` delegate :-

```
if section == 0 
{  
   // Note CGFloat.min for swift
   // For Objective-c CGFLOAT_MIN 
   let headerView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.myShaadiTableview.bounds.size.width, CGFloat.min)) 
   return headerView
}
else
{ 
   // Construct your other headers here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have more than one parent navigation controller? If that's the case, uncheck other parent navigation controllers' "Show Navigation Bar".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in swift:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude))
```

Answer (score 0):

For **iOS 15.0+**,

use this for removing extra padding at the top

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *){ 
    self.tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0.0 
}
```