# tableView + height of subView changes suddenly

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

Here is my code:

```
UIView * ivHeaderContainer = [[UIView alloc]init];
UIView * ivFooterContainer = [[UIView alloc]init];
UIImageView * ivHeader = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
UIImageView * ivFooter = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

PO1(self.tableHeaderView);
PO1(ivHeaderContainer);
self.tableHeaderView = ivHeaderContainer;
PO1(self.tableHeaderView);
PO1(ivHeaderContainer);
[ivHeaderContainer addSubview:ivHeader];
PO1(self.tableHeaderView);
```

Here is the log in console:

```
(41)> ivHeaderContainer: <UIView: 0x1a497700; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x1a497760>>
2014-01-24 12:15:11.441 domainname[13727:40ab] <0x1a490220 Image+imageFile.m:(30)> [NSString stringWithString: self.fullFileName]: /private/var/mobile/Applications/BF1CCA03-2406-4FC9-BE33-298AD6DBAC2C/tmp/http%3A%2F%2Fimg.agoda.net%2Fhotelimages%2F475%2F4755%2F4755_08091300010092992_std.jpg.png
2014-01-24 12:37:32.767 [13727:60b] <0x165ff400 BGTableViewWithBackgroundAndTopAndBottom.m:(43)> self.tableHeaderView: <UIView: 0x1a497700; frame = (0 35; 320 0); layer = <CALayer:
```

So, after the line

```
self.tableHeaderView = ivHeaderContainer
```

the value of `ivHeaderContainter` is suddenly `[0, 35, 320, 0]` instead of `[0, 0, 0, 0]`. Don't know where the number `35` comes from.

Only happens on one xib.
What could be the reason ?

Function PO1 (print object 1) simply print the stuff out.

This only happens when the table is grouped. But other grouped table doesn't have this issue.

Comment: What on earth does the function PO1 do? Zero chance of even guessing with method names like that...

Comment: It just print the stuffs.

Comment: Right, and the take-away is to explain that in your post with a simple comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declared the future tableViewHeader with this

```
UIView * ivHeaderContainer = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,.01,.01)];
```

Instead of

```
UIView * ivHeaderContainer = [[UIView alloc]init];
```

Problem is magically solved. It follows solutions here:     [Why is there extra padding at the top of my UITableView with style UITableViewStyleGrouped in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst)

Next question. Why?

Comment: There's no such thing as "next question" in an answer to a question on Stackoverflow. Maybe edit your original question?

Comment: I am saying that this answer leads to another natural question.