# Why 35 points padding when UITableViewHeader has height of 0 and in group mode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

This is related to:
[Why is there extra padding at the top of my UITableView with style UITableViewStyleGrouped in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst)

[tableView + height of subView changes suddenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325243/tableview-height-of-subview-changes-suddenly/21374613#21374613)

In fact, it's so obviously a bug. Simply making the future UITableView header to (0,0,.1,.1) works to fix the problem.

Comment: Have you filed a bug report with Apple?

Comment: how to do so again? I forget.

Comment: http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

This is bug of iOS, I guess. If you use storyboard, just remove tableView from controller and put it again. It solved a problem in my case.

Comment: I did that. However, when the tableView is on group mode it happened again.