# UITableView ScrollView not going to top of frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I am setting my UITableView frame to be just below another view on the y-axis.  I do not want the UITableView to go under the view higher on the y axis, like it would a UINavigationBar.  In this image the scroll indicators are at the very top.  [image]

But As you can see the inset is not at the top of the tableview.  I am assuming that this is because the UITableView is normally used at the top of a UINavigationBar and the scrollview insets are adjusted accordingly, but I don't want that.  I've tried setting the following to to UIEdgeInsetMake(0,0,0,0), but it does nothing.

tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets

tableView.contentInset

tableView.contentOffset (to CGPointMake(0,0))

I remember seeing something in iOS 7 tech talks about this, but I've searched through them for the past little bit and haven't found it.

Thanks!!

```
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
```

@"V:|-(NavBarHeight)-[otherView]-(0)-[tableView]-(0)-|"

Comment: is your tableView style Grouped or Plain? Choose Plain

Comment: Need to see codes of how to set up the top view and your uitableview. Did you use autolayout?

Comment: Grouped, and yes using auto layout.

Comment: If I use Plain or Grouped, it does the same either way.  Same with Autolayout vs not Autolayout.  Doesn't change it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I found the solution using this: `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` on this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try to uncheck the properties of the viewcontroller mentioned in the Screenshot according to your need. I hope this might help you,

[image]

Comment: Yup, that was my problem.  I'm not using Storyboards so I was doing this in code.  Didn't realize it would affect each UITableView in that UIViewController.  Good to know I guess.  If you could it would be nice if you added something like the following to your answer:


Put this in your -viewDidLoad; in the UIViewController that has the UITableView.

self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;