# Airplay route options popover

Tags: ios, ios8

I'm having a problem with the airplay route options popover drawing too short on iOS 8, such that the user can't even tell that there are options other than iPad available. In the attached screenshot, there are actually two airplay speakers available. You can scroll down and select them, but I doubt most users would think to try that.

I inspected the view hierarchy to see if there was a view corresponding to where it was choosing to bound the popover, but didn't see anything interesting.

The same issue was posted in the apple developer forums, but doesn't have an answer: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1039783#1039783

This happens in both portrait and landscape mode, 100% of the time on an iPad 3rd gen running 8.0.2. Built with Xcode 6.

Let me know if more information would be helpful, and thanks in advance for any thoughts!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an actual bug in iOS 8 apps built with Xcode 6. I created a test app and submitted it to apple as part of a Technical Support Incident. They examined it, credited us back the TSI and said they would track it as a bug. We also confirmed with another music application that they were seeing the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks for getting them a bug report, hopefully fixed soon!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Apple!  Great job with that whole iOS 8 thing, it seems to be going swimmingly!

I don't have a fix, but I can make it about 2x better with this magic incantation:

```
    [UITableView appearance].tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 10, 0.01f)];
```

The gray gap between the nav bar and the menu choices is caused by having a tableHeaderView set to nil, which I found from another SO question: [Why is there extra padding at the top of my UITableView with style UITableViewStyleGrouped in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst).  Then, you set your prototype table view to have the workaround.

The risk here is that you could potentially screw up other table views in your app.  I so far have not been able to find an appearanceWhenContainedIn magic that will select this broken audio route picker.  But in my app at least, the tables are fine, because none of them had header views anyway.

(Note that the thing that says "Airplay" is a prototype UINavigationBar, so if you need to modify that, you can as well -- but only if you want to apply it to all the nav bars in your app!  Again, I can't find an appearanceWhenContainedIn that works for me)