# Empty white space above UITableView inside a UIView

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder

I'm trying to position a TableView inside my ViewController view but leaving a 44 height gap between the bottom of the navigation bar and the top of the table. I then wanted to place a UITextField inside that gap to act as a stationary header. For some reason, the TableView has an empty white space above the start of the "Prototype Cells". Its just white space. Here is what it looks like in the storyboard.

[image: storyboard]

When viewing the app display, this is what it looks like:

[image: app1]

When scrolling the table, it goes all the way up to the correct place:

[image: app2]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there extra padding at the top of my UITableView with style UITableViewStyleGrouped in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Try to look in the 'attribute inspector' (in the right menu) of the Participants ViewController. 
Check for the option **'Extend Edges'** and uncheck the 'Under Top Bars', and then relocate your tableview.

Another possible solution is to just uncheck the option **'Adjust Scroll View Insets'**. 
The reason is that when the viewController extends its edges, let's say under the top bar, the tableView's scrollView automatically adjusts its inset top, so that the content of the tableView will start exactly under the top bar. But in your case this is not needed, since your tableView itself starts under the bar.

Focus on the ViewController and got to the Attribute Inspector tab:

[image]

Comment: Great! This works well except that the "Enter name" text field is not visible when in landscape mode. Perhaps its hidden below the table because the navigation bar is thinner?

Comment: Sounds like just a simple case for constraints. Try to set constraint for the textField - 'Top Space to Top Layout Guide', this should cause the textField to be under the top layout guide by the constant you set, in this case, the topLayoutGuide is exactly the bottom of the navigation bar.

Comment: Just updated my answer with a better solution. by the way, I just want to emphasize that it doesn't related to header view, as the other answer suggested... at least not as I see it..

Comment: The second paragraph of your answer works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks you sir! This is my first 'V' :)

Answer (score 13):

Try this one:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-65, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: what is strange is that none of the solutions helped except of yours.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Thanks @Natividad!

Answer (score 9):

Just add this in you ViewDidLoad method

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Answer (score 6):

change your table view style from grouped to plain

[image: as shown here]

Comment: Thanks! this works for me, but mine is change Plain to Grouped!

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to change the default setting for Extend Edges.

Looks like the real problem is a blank table header view in your storyboard. It's showing in the screenshot you provided of your storyboard, right below the Enter Name view and right above the Prototype Cells view. Delete it.

Comment: Perhaps I am being crazy but how do you delete the blank table header view? I can't click on anything in that blank space.

Comment: Maybe it's me. If you expand the Table View in the Structure editor on the left, what do you see? What is in that white space? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: The fact the space disappears when you scroll the table suggests the white space is part of the table view. The only way I know of is if you have a header view in your table.

Answer (score 1):

My issues is, I set `tableHeaderView` as new `UIView` like this

```
self.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

Remove this line, the issue is gone. Try this:

```
//self.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the 2022, iOS 15 solution if anyone stumbles upon this.

```swift
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    UITableView.appearance().sectionHeaderTopPadding = CGFloat(0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using iOS 15 or greater and section headers are being used: this will likely not solve the issue, even though as of May 2023, only solutions like these are the ones popping up in search engines.

iOS 15 introduced `UITableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding`, which is not 0 by default. So you need:

```
let tableView = UITableView()
tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69322250/2611730) on another post is what relieved me from 2 hours of trying to figure this out.

Comment: Sure thing! Really stupid that I tried to comment this answer in a bunch of places with people trying these < iOS 15 solutions and they all got removed because of duplication or something. Sometimes duplication is necessary in a decentralized place like the web, Stackoverflow admins...

Answer (score 0):

> I just found a solution for this.
>   In my case, i was using TabBarViewController, A just uncheck the option 'Adjust Scroll View Insets'. Issues goes away.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgQI8.png

Answer (score -1):

For Objective-C folks, add this in your ViewDidLoad method.

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 0, 0, 0)];
```