# White background at the top of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` below a `UITextField`. Strangely, the upper part of the `UITableView` has a white background. The tableView scrolls nicely till just below the `UITextField`, so it is being placed correctly below it. It is just that the upper portion is somehow getting a white background. And this portion seems to scale with respect to the height of the `UITextField`. i.e. if I increase the height of the textField, the white portion will increase too.

I have tried setting the adjust scroll view insets to false but to no avail.

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827315/empty-white-space-above-uitableview-inside-a-uiview

Comment: Check the last answer also, make sure you have not accidentally added some header to your tableView inside storyboard.

Comment: I have tried the suggested answers there. Mine is a little different. The tableView display properly. It is sitting just right below the textField, but the background of the upper portion is white. I have checked that there was no header under the tableView in storyboard.

Comment: If you look at the screenshot, the spacing is the exact height as the UINavigationController. I would guess that you have some wierd hierarcy with multiple navigationControllers. Make sure you are pushing/presenting this UIViewController correctly. If this solves your issue let me know I will update as the answer since I don't find something similiar. I answered something like this before but I cant find the post unfortunately.

Comment: There is actually no spacing. Just white background, and it scales along with the `UITextField`'s height at the top.

Comment: What happens if you remove the UITextField and simply constraint the uitableview to the top of the superView?

Comment: You could run the application and check in the debug view hierarchy what exactly is happening!

Comment: @MaTaKazer remove your text field and add it as `tableview header`

Answer (score 0):

layout and its constraints are looking fine, I think you might have added a header view in code. Can you check your delegate and data source functions in your class.

Comment: **Do not use answers as comment section** also read the comments below the actual question and you will see your suggestion has already been tested.

Answer (score 0):

Go to storyboard and select view controller where your tableview is and 
[image]
[image]

Unmark option Adjust ScrollView Insets

Comment: OP said he has already done that

Comment: Give each view different color and then check which view it is ? Otherwise in viewdidload()
{//give frame to tableview by setting y = textfield.frame.origin.y + textfield.frame.size.height
}

Comment: **I have tried setting the adjust scroll view insets to false but to no avail.**

Answer (score 0):

By default an section height and footer of **28** is added to the tableview in xib.

Change it **1** for both header and footer in the size inspector.

[image: tableview section header and height]