# View over tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have the following screen (image) which shows a side menu when the button is pressed the menu appears, plus I have a uitableview to show other things

[image]

my problem is that when the side menu appears the uitableview is resized.

How do I keep my uitableview intact?
I've been trying the next but I have not got anything:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Vmenu_usuario: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! 

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.sendSubview(toBack:tableView)
        view.bringSubview(toFront:Vmenu_usuario)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete White space view over tableview

uncheck the option 'Adjust Scroll View Insets'.

[image]

more detail: [Empty white space above UITableView inside a UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827315/empty-white-space-above-uitableview-inside-a-uiview)

Hope this hellp.