# iOS 15: Remove empty space before cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I am using `UITableView` for a multi-section list. The issue I am seeing is a space above the cells of each section, even if I set `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)` to be 0. This occurs even when there is only one section and I set `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` to be `nil`.

I have tried all other answers on StackOverflow relating to inset overrides/edge expanding but none have worked.

Example:

[image: Screenshot of iOS table view. Above each section header is a gap which is the same colour as the table background.]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Check if you are only seeing this issue on iOS 15 and above. If so, this may be caused by the newly introduced [`UITableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/3750914-sectionheadertoppadding) property. You will need to set this value to `0` in order to remove the spacing before section headings:

```swift
let tableView = UITableView()
tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0

// Etc.
```

This property is only available >= iOS 15 so you will need an API check if building for earlier versions.

If you're not on iOS 15, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst) has most of the answers to this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. This should be more widely linked to on the ~2018 era results on this problem which I bounced between for the past 2 hours, because those results get the most traffic.

Comment: @monstermac77 feel free to do that to help people in the future :)

Comment: Just posted it in a couple places! Thanks again. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76337142/2611730

Comment: I logged in just to upvote this!  As mentioned, this is the only answer that makes sense since iOS 15.

Answer (score 9):

Another approach is to set the `sectionHeaderTopPadding` value found in UITableView's `UIAppearance` proxy, which ensures that the value will be applied to every instance of UITableView in your application:

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    UITableView.appearance().sectionHeaderTopPadding = CGFloat(0)
}
```