# iOS weird spacing before the first UITableVIewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

There are tons of questions in the area but I can't seem to get it working.

I have a `UITableView` with autolayout 0 distance to superview from all edges.
`ViewController` has under opaque bars on (my NavigationBar is opaque)
AdjustScrollView inset is ON (and gets a nice `contentOffset: {0, -64};`)

The first cell has a weird spacing of additional 35 px:

```
po [self.view recursiveDescription]
<UIView: 0x7fc8a28159c0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc8a2816d80>>
   | <UITableView: 0x7fc8a1a4d000; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc8a2a3ea90>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc8a2a23450>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {320, 1429}>
   |    | <UITableViewWrapperView: 0x7fc8a2a01670; frame = (0 0; 320 568); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc8a2810d80>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc8a2a25590>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 568}>
   |    |    | <MomentHeaderTableViewCell: 0x7fc8a2ad1630; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 35; 320 504); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc8a2a02110>>
```

Where is it coming from?

Comment: i think your tableview start from the status bar not from your navigation bar there for your tableview offset is -64.

Comment: but the cell is actually on 64+35...

Comment: no need to add content offset. you can set y coordinate to 0.

Comment: I'm not adding content offset, it is created due to AdjustScrollView

Answer (score 0):

What did the trick was:
`self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 0.01f)];`

Found here:
[Why is there extra padding at the top of my UITableView with style UITableViewStyleGrouped in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst)