# Unexpected behaviour of scrollview indicator in UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, vertical-scrolling, uisearchcontroller

After hitting  Search button for UISearchController, scroll indicator is stopping at keyboard height.
I logged contentsize, it is printing it as **1056.000000**
EdgeInsets are 0s for all parameters 
[scroll indicator image](http://postimg.org/image/ujysnu47v/)

any suggestions for make it proper

Answer (score 1):

got the problem, need to set insets to zero

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    [tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    [tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, you might be having the same issue I had, which was fixed by going into the Storyboard and *reordering* the controls on your particular iOS screen:

[Why is there extra padding at the top of my UITableView with style UITableViewStyleGrouped in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst/27815006#27815006)

This bug is still alive, kicking and annoying in iOS 8.2, and seems to affect any standard iOS controls with a vertical scrollbar  (UITableView, UIScrollView, UITextView, etc)