# Spacing between UITableview header and top cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm getting some odd behavior with my UITableView.

There's spacing between my UITableView Header and the first cell. Any idea why this is?

```
#define kDefaultTableViewSectionHeight 50

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.posts.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return kDefaultTableViewCellHeight;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return kDefaultTableViewSectionHeight;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, kDefaultTableViewSectionHeight)];
    UIButton *hot = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 0, 100, kDefaultTableViewSectionHeight)];
    UIButton *new = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-100, 0, 100, kDefaultTableViewSectionHeight)];
    UIView *underline = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(new.frame.origin.x, view.frame.size.height-10, 70, 1)];
    UIView *border = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, view.frame.size.height-1, view.frame.size.width, 1)];

    [border setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:50.0/255.0 blue:50.0/255.0 alpha:1]];

    self.underline = underline;

    if (self.new)
        [underline setCenter:CGPointMake(new.center.x, underline.center.y)];
    else
        [underline setCenter:CGPointMake(hot.center.x, underline.center.y)];

    [underline setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [hot setTitle:@"Hot" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [hot setTag:2];
    [hot setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [hot addTarget:self action:@selector(selectQueryType:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [hot.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Heavy" size:20.0]];

    [new setTitle:@"New" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [new setTag:1];
    [new setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [new addTarget:self action:@selector(selectQueryType:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [new.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Heavy" size:20.0]];

    [view addSubview:new];
    [view addSubview:hot];
    [view addSubview:underline];
    [view addSubview:border];
    return view;
}
```

I've tried the following code to fix the issue, but this just reduces the space between the top of the UITableView and the UINavigationBar:

```
    /*
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7){
        self.postTableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-8, 0, 0, 0);
    } */
```

but this just reduces the spacing between the top of the UITableView and the UINavigationbar.

[image]

Comment: Here you have another question where you probably will find an answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst

Comment: @ClaudioRedi my problem is different, since the spacing *starts* at the header and *ends* at the top of the first cell.

Comment: one of the answers talks about setting 0 for section header. I recommend you to take a deeper look since there are many different answers.

Comment: are you using delegate for setting the headerView?

have you checked the height returned by:

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section? `

`kDefaultTableViewSectionHeight *50*`

from the image i think it's at around 35 or something try declaring lesser value  to `kDefaultTableViewSectionHeight`

Comment: @0yeoj Yes it's in my the code of my question above

Comment: under `-(void)viewDidLoad` you have self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO; ?

Comment: @0yeoj yep, tried this and it has no affect

Comment: I currently testing your code above and it is working fine without any modification, hmm..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the `tableHeaderView` property with the section header view. The delegate method `tableview:viewForHeaderInSection:` that you are calling sets the header of the section rather than the header of the `UITableView` itself. In your `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:` you are only returning 1 section, so you just add your custom header as a header of the tableview rather than it being the header of the first section in the tableview. This doesn't solve your specific problem, but it seems to be a better solution for your app considering there will on be only 1 section in the tableview.

In `-viewDidLoad` you can simply set the `tableHeaderView` property to your custom view as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

  //...

  _tableview.tableHeaderView = [self myTableHeader];

}

- (UIView *)myTableHeader{

  //Return custom header view 

}
```

Comment: I want to have the header stay at the top as you scroll thought