# Extra white space above table view swift Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I had an error with Xcode where I needed to fix the size class. After I did that, I went back to one of my table views, and it added white space above the first prototype cells in the tableview. How can I get rid of that space? I added this picture below to better describe what I mean.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ebxipb0r2jakav/TableViewProblem.png?dl=0

```
@IBOutlet var schoolTable: UITableView!

var namesArray = [String]()
var locationsArray = [String]()

var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

var theSchoolName: String = "None Selected"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    namesArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    locationsArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Schools")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            if let objects = query.findObjects() as? [PFObject] {

                for object in objects {

                    self.namesArray.append(object.valueForKey("schoolName") as! String)
                    self.locationsArray.append(object.valueForKey("schoolLocation") as! String)

                    self.schoolTable.reloadData()

                }
            }
        } else {
            println("Oops, it didn't work...")
        }
    }

}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.namesArray.count
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:ChangeSchoolListTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! ChangeSchoolListTableViewCell

    if namesArray.count > 0 {
        cell.nameLabel.text = namesArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.locationLabel.text = locationsArray[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: provide code sample please

Comment: @iAnurag I added the code above. It wasn't anything I did with the code, but rather in the storyboard. I don't know what happened/how to get it back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this a lot with Xcode storyboards.

The solution is to move the UITableView so its not the first view on the screen.

[image]

[Space at the top of UITableViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst/27815006#27815006)

Comment: I tried adding a search bar, and thus making it the second view, but it still has the extra space.