# Table view top space to navigation bar increased after pressing back

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When I click one of the cells in the table view, it opens a new view with the following code:

```
   let fullResView : FullResponseViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FullResponseView") as! FullResponseViewController
   fullResView.receivedPost = post
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(fullResView, animated: false)
```

When I press back, it increases the distance between the table view and the Top Layout Guide. Representation:

[image: table view navigation controller error.]

**Hierarchy:**

- I have a tab bar controller, that is embedded in a navigation controller.
- The table view is drag & dropped after creating an normal view. So the table view is inside a View.
- Table view does contain an header view. When setting a background color for this, it moves together with it, so it should not be anything with those constraints.

**constraints for the table view are:**

- equal with to superview
- Align Center X to superview
- top space to Top Layout Guide
- bottom space to Bottom Layout Guide

I've tried the following:

set this in viewWillAppear:

```
self.responsesTableView.contentOffset =  CGPointMake(0, 0)
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

This did work when I pressed back, then switch to another view in the tab bar, and then switch back again. Without `contentOffset` it will stay like this forever.

Comment: try to set background color for the View that contains you table view, and let me see that which view the white space belong to ?

Comment: the white space belongs to the View that contains the table view. Nitin Gohel, any suggestions?

Comment: Well Nitin, you can make this an answer, or Gintama, or togheter :) But I don't get it, nowhere in my workspace I could find something with `translucent`, still, setting this to false in app delegate did the trick...but why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As i seen the OP images that seems like Navigation **translucent** property Issue. Because after push a viewcontroller there is same 44px white space. so it means if your Navigation **translucent** property is true then your `UITableview` start from 0th Y position. And if your Navigation **translucent** property is false then `UITableview` start from 44px Y position.

So i guess in between push and back some where UINavigation's **translucent** become a true and false. make following one line add in your appdelegate class in DidFinish method:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
```

This is `appearance` of `UINavigationBar` for make this false globley in your project. Hope that will be fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is related to your particular issue, but it's worth checking whether your `UITableView` is the first control on your screen:

[Why is there extra padding at the top of my UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst/27815006#27815006)

Even in the latest version of Xcode, this is a bug.  But it's easy enough to fix, if you know how to get around it.

[image]