# iOS 9 height of UITable section header differ from iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

I am wonder to see difference between iOS 9 and iOS 8 framing difference .
I create a table with sections header and return section header's height 22 and its matching with iOS contact app's contact list section header (alphabet separator) with iOS 8 . but with iOS 9 22 seems very thiner in comparison with iOS 9 contact list native app.

Please suggest how to maintain this differences

Comment: Is that what r u talking about? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst