# UITableview refreshing cells scrolling under section header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, pull-to-refresh, uitableviewsectionheader

I am using [UzysCircularProgressPullToRefresh](https://github.com/uzysjung/UzysCircularProgressPullToRefresh) in order to refresh my tableview.
My UITableView have 1 static section with a title and I want it always fixed at the top of the table(That's why I don't want to use UITableViewStyleGrouped).
When the UITableView is in refreshing state, and I start scrolling it, the cells are being scrolling under the header section which is very bad as a design.
Kindly check the image 
[image: check the Image here]

You can test it by yourself by adding the following to the project:

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"Header Section";
}
```

I tried to find a solution  but didn't find any after lot of searching.
Can anyone help me solving this? how to fix this design issue in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat navBarMaxY = CGRectGetMaxY(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame);
    if (scrollView.contentInset.top > navBarMaxY) {
        if (scrollView.contentInset.top > -scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            UIEdgeInsets insets = scrollView.contentInset;
            insets.top = MAX(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, navBarMaxY);
            scrollView.contentInset = insets;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly on portrait, but it is still facing the issue in landscape mode

Comment: It was example. I thought that you will continue by yourself. I updated my answer.

Comment: You're awesome :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself once.

For me, the solution was to drag'n'drop the `UITableView` so it *wasn't* the first element in my view.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27815006/391605

Dumb, hey ?  Give it a go.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not using xib in my project. It is all written by code. You can also check it in the UzysCircularProgressPullToRefresh project from GitHub.

Comment: Even if you're not using a .xib file, what you're seeing does look identical to the Xcode bug I was seeing...  So, it might still be worth *inserting* a component as the first subview item in your UIViewController.