# iOS - Excess of space in TableView header

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I have two tabs and two different tables in each tab. There is a button below each table. I'm using the same constraints for both of them, and yet in one tab, my table header is using too much space and pushing the actual table down.

**Here's the normal table:**

[image]

**The table I'm having trouble with:**

[image]

**Here are the constraints I'm using:**

[image]

I've been searching for a solution online for hours and even recreated the entire layout and code. I have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: Do both tables have the same style? The second screenshot looks grouped.

Comment: Yes, both are grouped. -checked now to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19117685/3038563) answered my question.

> YourStoryboard.storyboard > YourViewController > Attributes inspector > Uncheck - Adjust scroll view insets.