# How to remove the white space from the above the header view of a table view in swift?

Tags: ios, swift2, tableview

[Screen shot of my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ufJ4.png) I have a header view in a table view as shown in the image. I want to start it from the top. but there is a white space between the top space bar and the header view. I did uncheck the `Adjust scroll view insect`.I want my header view just below the time displayed. I want the header view of the UITableView to appear in the navigation bar. i don't want the white space for the navigation bar. I have also set Top Bar = None in the storyboard

[image]

Comment: In your storyboard, you simulate top bar to none. It does not have any impact at runtime. Does your storyboard show this white space when you don't simulate to none?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there extra padding at the top of my UITableView with style UITableViewStyleGrouped in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst)

Comment: Tom, the top bar has no effect on the story board.

Comment: Akilan, I did follow that link. But my problem is different.

Comment: You can get rid of the top space using `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -offsetTop, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)` where `offsetTop` is the height of the blank space. HOWEVER, if your table has vertical bounce on scroll enabled then the white space will still show when the user drags the tableview down. I am still not sure how to resolve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

in your viewcontroller in viewDidLoad.

Comment: sanman, it does not solve the issue. I did try with  self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

Comment: Can you add storyboard or xib screenshot?...it might be of help.