# Table View extra padding above first cell in Table View - only on iPad Pro

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I looked at all of the answers here [Why is there extra padding at the top of my UITableView with style UITableViewStyleGrouped in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)
and none of them worked.

I have a table view within a UIViewController, and a collection view inside the header of the table view so that I can have a parallax scrolling effect. When the view first loads, there's no empty space above the first cell. After tapping a new item in the collection view, the table view is reloaded and the empty space appears. A curious thing is that this bug is only presenting itself on the iPad Pro (simulator). I tested on the simulator for the iPad 2 and iPad Air (1 & 2) and there's no issue. Please see the attached images.
[image: working upon first load]
[image: broken upon tapping new item in collection view]

Consolidated list of things I have tried:

1. Setting self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None in viewDidLoad()
2. Setting self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
3. Returning 0 for heightForHeaderInSection
4. Unchecking "extend under top bars" and "under bottom bars" in IB