# Q: tableView created by storyboard running appears space form the top to the first cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

Create the `tableView` in the `storyboard`, and set the constraints to arrive the all around. 
But when running on simulator, there appear some space form the top to the first cell.

The issue on simulator:

[image: on the simulator]

The Debug View Hierarchy:

[image: Debug View Hierarchy]

And in the storyboard i set the constraints :

[image: constraints]

Comment: write    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;  in the viewDidLoad method

Comment: @yagneshdobariya in fact this has been answered a gazillion times already.

Comment: @Adeel Yes too many time...!!!

Comment: @Adeel and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate

Comment: @aircraft yes that's right, if your question contains different key words then you should keep your question. The answer in the link that you provided explains the matter very well. So it's okay if your question gets marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Check this answer. I hope it will work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75810644/12775090

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the attribute inspector of your view controller try to disable Adjust Scroll View Inset, see below image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if your navigation bar is translucent then you can unselect the adjust scroll view insets for your view controller in storyboard

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your constraints

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the attribute inspector of your view controller try to disable `Extended Edges->underTopBar`

[image]

Comment: Please check if the tableview is grouped/plain in Attributes Inspector. In my case I have changed the style to plain and it worked. Now the extra spacing above the header has disappeared.