# ios first cell is not start from top of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My Application has a navigation and UITableView. I set backgroundColor to my tableView. Look at the picture bellow. I don't understand why the first cell is not started from top of UITableView.
When I use View Debbuger in Xcode, TableViewWrapperView is not fulled in UITableView.

I already searched many times. I removed check `Adjust Scroll View Insets` and set `.zero` tableview's `contentinsets`. At last I made New Project and make it again but I can't.

How can I resolve this problem!!

[image]

Comment: you are using xib or storybord?

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280134/q-tableview-created-by-storyboard-running-appears-space-form-the-top-to-the-fir/40280181#40280181

Comment: what is your origin y of the tableview?

Comment: @seggy I'm using storyboard

Comment: @SahebRoy origin y is 64.

Comment: and the pink color is probably the color of the view, right?

Comment: I'm using tab bar too. Is it different to normal viewcontroller?

Comment: Um.. Pink color is tableView's background color. Not Viewcontroller's view color.

Comment: @SahebRoy Thank you for answer my question. I resolve problem.

Answer (score 10):

## Simple Solution for this issue

No need to code for this issue. Just follow below simple step

YourStoryboard.storyboard > YourViewController > Attributes inspector > **Uncheck - Adjust scroll view insets.**

Here I attached screenshot for reference.

[image]

If you like go with code I have also solution :)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is for the souls like me who tried everything above and might have missed this. I accidentally used tableview style as Grouped instead of Plain.

So set your Tableview style to "Plain" instead of "Grouped" in xib/storyboard or in code as

Objective C

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Swift 4,0

```
self.tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .plain)
```

Comment: i got this issue after refactoring, I forgot that i changed the tableview style in the proces. after two hours of checking the diff, debugging and googling I finally came actoss ur answer. The word style trigger i needed. Thnx due and thanx SO 

Comment: I can feel the pain bro :-)

Answer (score 5):

The table view tries to adjust itself to accommodate the navigation bar assuming that navigation bar is translucent and it has to display itself behind it.

To resolve this issue in the storyboard/xib file set the view controller property extends edges under top bar to false as shown below.

[image]

Comment: When I unselect "under top bars" the navigation bar's background changes color. Any idea how to keep it the same as when it is selected?

Comment: @spijs This might be because your navigation bar might have a alpha to its background color. You might want a solid color for the background to maintain consistency.

Answer (score 5):

Found it for iOS 11 and above, use:

```
    self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Answer (score 2):

Open the storyboard, click on the `UITableView`. In your `sizeInspector` set the `Header`and `Footer` in section height field to be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Open your storyboard and click on the table view controller/view controller that contains the table view. Open the attribute inspector and untick `Adjust Scroll View Insets`.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question.

I don't know what is different to `top layout guide` and `view`.
But I resolve to set top constraint 0 to `view`.

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXeHB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Write this two line on viewdidload of your viewcontroller, it will fix your issue

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

solution post iOS 11

```
tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Answer (score 0):

I have try the code below, but it did not work.

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;  
_tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;  
_tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
```

My solution:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1.0;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                                              0.0,
                                                              self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                                                              1.0)];
    header.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    
    return header;
}
```