# Extra space is getting added in UITableView top while updating tableview datasource property

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios10

When I try to update the tableview datasource property as shown below

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView?.delegate = self
    tableView?.dataSource = self

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView?.delegate = nil
    tableView?.dataSource = nil

    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

I am getting an extra space on top of the Tableview when I navigate to other screen and come back to this screen, can anyone help resolving the issue ?

[image]

To

[image]

Note* I am tried this in simulator with version 10.2

Comment: Try self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO; can be set from code or storyboard itself.

Comment: @BharatModi : Ya, I tried that too, but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Ara you using headerView?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst

Comment: @BharatModi: Yes, I have used header view using a custom cell. I have also removed the headerview and I have also tried without header view, but the issue still persists.

Comment: @BharatModi: Thank you, I have also first tried some of the answers in the same link you shared, but I got that issue only when I newly added that tableView?.dataSource = code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the header height as 0. This works most of times. If not also try setting an empty view with 0 height to the header view of the table view.

If you are using the AutomaticDimension to update the cell heights. Make sure to set the .estimatedHeight property to the minimum height you cell can have.