# Top Bar background in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have UITableViewController that can be accessed using segue from other ViewController that is inside UINavigationController.

My table has two sections with static cells
I also manually added view (dark navy color) with custom UIButton.

In interface builder it looks like this

[image]

But when I open my app in simulator - I get this stripe in the top. So I have few questions about this.

[image]

1) Where this stripe came from?

2) How can I make it disappear? I tried something like

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -16, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

I am not sure that this is right way.

3) For future - is it ok to add UIView to top of UITableViewController manually as I did

**Update**
This is debug view
[image]

Comment: yes, creating an `UIView` is ok solution, just create some function like `addStatusBarView(with color: UIColor)` and call whenever you want to add this view

Comment: What are you referring to by stripe? the status bar with the time and battery level?

Answer (score 1):

1. Debug your view to see why your header is higher. [Documentation Debugging in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html)
2. You don't
   need to remove it because it not normal. You probably using a wrong
   constant.
3. Yes, you can..

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

Comment: Great tool - thank you - never used it before. I updated my question with screenshot from it. So as I see it is not Status Bar?

Comment: I suggest following some tutorials/trainings in developing iOS apps. You'll learn a ton and feel more comfortable.

Comment: It probably is a setting on the `navigationItem`

Answer (score 0):

This spacing was solved with unchecking on of default View Controller properties in interface builder!

> YouStoryboard.storyboard > YouViewController > Attributes inspector > Uncheck - Adjust scroll view insets.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19117685/1218405