# UITableView extra space when having 2 tabs side by side sharing the same tableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, tableview

I have the same problem with this question: 
[Why is there extra padding at the top of my UITableView with style UITableViewStyleGrouped in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst)

I have tried so many solutions in this post, but none of them works for me. So i would like to post my project here so that every can take a look and help me find the solution.

[image]

https://github.com/happysmile09/TableViewIssue

Description: In tab 2, i scroll table view to bottom, then i move to tab1, the extra top space shows up.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need header height you can put following function to make height 0 and minimize the gap

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: No, this does not help! please help to check again

Answer (score 2):

Hope will help you ...

Add 2 row

> let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
>
> self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)

to 2 function ***didTapTab1*** and ***didTapTab2***

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help..Uncheck the Adjust autoScroll view inset..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following

First add **self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO** in your viewDidLoad() method

and then 
**Select TableView > Open Size Inspector > Set SectionHeight of Header to 1**

or you can use method also

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 1.0; 
 }
```