# Unwanted space above first section in UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I know there have been many similar questions (especially a lot of good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst)) but none of them seem to work for me hence asking the question.

So I have a plain tableview with a searchBar in Navigation bar.

[image]

Selecting the search leads up to this screen : [image]

Everything is ok for now, but if I go back to screen1 -> scroll down -> scroll up again (or tap the nav bar for autoscroll) -> select search again -> then there is a weird space above the first section on screen2. [image]

and if I repeat the steps then the gap keeps increasing.
[image]

I am using xcode 9.3, ios11 ,without autolayout (long story). 
I've been stuck here for quite some time so any help would be highly appreciated.

**Update**
A sample project can be found [here](https://github.com/didFinishLaunching/SearchGlitchesTest).

Comment: Add your code work.

Comment: Are you using `Grouped` table view style?

Comment: @dahiya_boy can't do that right now but I will soon.

Comment: @LalKrishna no I'm using plain tableview

Comment: How the height for header provided?

Comment: just added some sample code