# Margin before first Table View Section

Tags: ios, uitableview

Why do I have margin before first table view section?

Is it not supposed to be only between sections?

[image]

Comment: I've tried to reproduce here. It seems to me that this area that looks like a margin is actually its section without a title. The 'item' label is in its first cell

Comment: @ClaudioCastro I don't need titles

Comment: Ok, for me this border appeared when I changed the table from Plain to Grouped.

Comment: Maybe this can help yout. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst

Comment: @ClaudioCastro yes, I saw it. Tried first answer but it doesn't change anything https://stackoverflow.com/a/19117685/7767664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding

> > tableView (_tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int)

You will get the behavior you want at runtime. If you need to change the values according to the section, you need to do it manually by testing which section you are in.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
{ 
   if section == 0 {
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
   }else{
    return 44
   }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much

Comment: though margin between sections is smaller now, I just want to remove margin before first section but don't change it between sections

Comment: You have to test what section you are. I will change the example

Comment: it seems I just can increase values for header/footer height

Comment: actually there is margin in iOS settings app, so it's normal and we should not change it xD