# UITableView scroll indicator with unexpected top padding

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm developing a section of my app with a UITableView. I added it programmatically with this set of constraints. I'm not considering bottom safe area because I want content over it.

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customHeader.bottomAnchor),
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
])
```

So, I noticed this weird behavior of scroll indicator:

[image]

green is `customHeader`, blue is the tableView background color and orange is the first cell. When I pull down the tableview and I reach the first cell, the scroll indicator is not at ZERO position, but only graphically. In fact `tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets.top` is zero.

So I tried to set it to -20, for example, and the scroll indicator has its zero behind the `customHeader`, as expected. So it starts to appear outside the tableView.

I tried to set `tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets.top = .leastNonZeroMagnitude` and it works. Now the indicator starts at Zero.

I studied this behavior and I found that if I change the bottom constraint from:

`tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)`

to:

`tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)`

everything works fine, without the need to set manually the scroll indicator position. But in this way I lose the possibility to have table view content over safe area. I thought it could be a problem of `automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInsets` for the vc I'm working on, but it's not the case.

Any advice on this? I think it's a bug. I'm working with Xcode 11.4 and Swift 5.2.

Thanks.

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst

Comment: already consulted that: all the posted solutions don't work

Comment: Add these code in your view controller's viewDidLoad() method: tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero , tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero. Then look for you cellForRowAt method and add this: cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

Comment: separator? I'm asking for scrollIndicator, not separator