# how to remove iOS 15 extra top padding in swiftui InsetGroupedListStyle?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a InsetGroupedListStyle List in SwiftUI and noticed an extra top padding added in iOS 15.  How can I control or remove this?

```
List {
    Section(header: Text("Header")) {
        // some content
    }
}
.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
```

Here is iOS 14:

[image]

and iOS 15:

[image]

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68155090/extra-padding-above-table-view-headers-in-ios-15

Comment: This is useful but doesn't help in my case as the issue is not the section header top padding but actually the entire List top padding.

Comment: I'm wondering if it could be related to new refresh controls added to list in iOS15

Answer (score 7):

For fixing this problem you can use the [headerProminence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/headerprominence%28_:%29)

```
Section("Header") {
  // some content
}
.headerProminence(.increased)
```

[image: iOS 15 vs 14]

To fix the problem with table view

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *)
    UITableView.appearance().sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0;
```

***UPDATED:*** I think I found the solution for this specific case:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = .init(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
```

Comment: This works for sections but doesn't help in my case as the issue is not the section header top padding but actually the entire List top padding.  I tried this and made no difference.

Comment: did you tried setting `tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0.0` directly?

Comment: what do you mean directly.  I'm using swiftUI so no tableView.  Just a list and no modifier for sectionHeader.  That's why need to use UITableView.appearance()

Comment: @alionthego OK I understand you now, I've edited my answer

Comment: This is not the solution.  It's not to do with header prominence.  This is the list adding a top padding.

Comment: @alionthego I've added an image to show you the effect of headerProminence, please just try it out, I think it will help

Comment: I have tried and makes no difference.  I still have the extra space on iOS 15 which I don’t want.  It’s only at top of list. Not every section.

Comment: didn't work for me either. I am using SwiftUI

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check out out

Comment: `.headerProminence(.increased)` doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 6):

I had a similarly frustrating issue, doing this helped me

```
List {
    Section(header: Text("Header")) {
        // some content
    }
}
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```

Note this changed the colours of my headers