# There is extra space at the bottom of the table view when the table style is grouped

Tags: swift, tableview, footer

Good afternoon, I tried all the solutions I found on the Internet.
Here is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    let data = ["dwdwd","wdwddw","wddwdw"]
    let color = [UIColor.red,UIColor.blue,UIColor.green]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
        tableView.tableFooterView = nil
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.backgroundColor = color[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return tableView.bounds.height / 3
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return .leastNormalMagnitude
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return .leastNormalMagnitude
    }
    
}
```

I already tried the solution of creating a zero footer, but it didn’t help.
[Why is there extra padding at the top of my UITableView with style UITableViewStyleGrouped in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst) - this article didn’t help either

Comment: instead of .leastNormalMagnitude return 0.1 in heightforHeaderInSection this will do the trick

Comment: Grouped is set via storyboard? (Sorry I have to ask, I do my tables programmatically)

Comment: tables are created via storyboard
what's the point of returning 0.1 if leastNormalMagnitude is still less.
I tried returning 0.1, it didn't help